# Is there a way to add a condition to display/hide button for use in different component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application.

I want to add a button aligned with the pagination buttons (Previous, Next) in for navigating tables.

I've tried to do this by duplicating the Table.js that points to different component (index.js). Is there a more efficient way to add the button using 1 Table.js file, and adding a variable in the index.js as an indicator for displaying/hiding the added button? Or have a better implementation? Thank you

Display Button 1 on component 1 only
Display Button 2 on component 2 only

```
pagination = pageOptions.length ? (
    <Pagination {...getRowProps()}>
      <Cell>
        <Button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          Previous
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          Next
        </Button>{" "}
        <span>
          Page{" "}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{" "}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{" "}
          <Input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
              gotoPage(page);
            }}
            style={{ width: "100px" }}
          />
        </span>{" "}
        <Select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>{" "}
        **<Button onClick={() => test1()}>BUTTON1</Button> -> Display only on component 1
        <Button onClick={() => test2()}>BUTTON2</Button> -> Display only on component 2**
      </Cell>
    </Pagination>
  ) : null;

  return (
    <div>
      <Table {...getTableProps()}>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <HeaderRow {...headerGroup.getRowProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <Header
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                sorted={column.sorted}
                sortedDesc={column.sortedDesc}
                sortedIndex={column.sortedIndex}
              >
                <div>
                  <span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </span>{" "}
                  {/* {column.canGroupBy ? (
                                        <Emoji {...column.getGroupByToggleProps()}>
                                            {column.grouped ? "" : ""}
                                        </Emoji>
                                    ) : null} */}
                </div>
                {column.canFilter ? <div>{column.render("Filter")}</div> : null}
              </Header>
            ))}
          </HeaderRow>
        ))}
        {tableBody}
        <Row {...getRowProps()}>
          {loading ? (
            <Cell>
              <strong>Loading...</strong>
            </Cell>
          ) : (
            <Cell>{rows.length} Total Records</Cell>
          )}
        </Row>
        {pagination}
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use state in this case.
And change the state from witch component is mounted right now. You can use the react lifecycle methods `componentDidMount(){}` and `componentWillUnmount() {}` for setting state. 
And then just check the state and add the button.
[State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) - check the docs, it will answer a lot